# How do I setup a Docker repo file to pull Docker from in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, configuration, kubernetes

I am setting up a cluster for Kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04 machines and I am doing some configurations. The instructions I am following, however, are for CentOS 7 where they set up a file called  `/etc/yum.repos.d/virt7-docker-common-release.repo` which contains the following:

```
[virt7-docker-common-release]
name=virt7-docker-common-release
base-url=http://cbs.centos.org/repos/virt7-docker-common-release/x86_64/os/
gpgcheck=0
```

My question what is the equivalent file under Ubuntu 16.04, what is it file path and what are its contents?

Comment: Any reason why not to follow the installation guidelines on Ubuntu?https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's adding the yum repository that let the OS know where to find the binaries that you try to install (kubernetes, etcd and flannel). Something similar in Ubuntu 16.04 would be

```
echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" \
  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list \
  && sudo apt-get update
```

Althought you'd have to first add the required key using

```
sudo apt-get update \
  && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
  && curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

[Here there is a guide](https://blog.alexellis.io/kubernetes-in-10-minutes/) that talks about installing kubernetes on Ubuntu.

Comment: any news on this @Tendekai-muchenje?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to install docker on your machine? If so, you don't really need to do anything with a repo file. Docker 1.13 is available inside of the Ubuntu repository by default. You can just run the following to get this installed:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install docker.io
```